# Encrypt Sidekiq's connection to Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

We currently have Sidekiq setup with Azure Redis Cache and would like to encrypt the connection between them. After a little googling I came across [a recently merged pull request](https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/6236) that adds native encryption to Redis but this as of yet has not been released. I have seen people suggest Stunnel but I was wondering if there were any alternatives to this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidekiq uses the [`redis`](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) gem which has [SSL/TLS support](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/5b3de8d25321693f0a30d4e4748a9d48edb49bbf/README.md#ssltls-support) if you provide a connection URL using the `rediss://` scheme (second 's' is not a typo).

```
# https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/1317ecb518c2d0d0263f1cfc49f104cea3ea24b3/lib/redis/cluster/option.rb#L29
class Redis
  class Cluster
    class Option
      DEFAULT_SCHEME = 'redis'
      SECURE_SCHEME = 'rediss'

      # ...

      def secure?
        @node_uris.any? { |uri| uri.scheme == SECURE_SCHEME } || @options[:ssl_params] || false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I've used this with AWS ElastiCache which supports [in-transit encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/in-transit-encryption.html). The Azure docs suggest [Azure Cache has similar SSL capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure#access-ports).

Comment: I don't have any public code I can link to showing this, but a quick Github search reveals this in the wild: https://github.com/ministryofjustice/prison-visits-2/blob/b8a6b3bce59b21e89245fadb3ced67bf9dc60059/config/initializers/kubernetes_sidekiq_configuration.rb#L4